# Why is the following only scraping one page? How can I scrape the other pages as well?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape multiple pages, but the following code scrapes only one page. How can I scrape the other pages?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
for page in range(0, 10):
    r =requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=sneakers&_sacat=0&_pgn={}".format(page * 10)') 
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    tags=  soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': 's-item'})
for pro in tags:
    title=pro.find('h3',class_='s-item__title').text.encode("utf-8")
    price=pro.find('div',class_='s-item__detail s-item__detail--primary').text.encode("utf-8")
    

    print(title,price)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=sneakers&_sacat=0&_pgn={}".format(page * 10)') ` looks incorrect. You'll need to fix the string format here for this code to work at all. Secondly, indentation is off -- `for pro in tags` should be nested inside of `for page in range`.

Comment: I give the range of page and also try string but  it not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now using correct locator, I'm getting working output:

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


Title = []
p = []

headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
}
for page in range(0, 10):
    r =requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=sneakers&_sacat=0&_pgn={page}'.format(page=page), headers = headers) 
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    tags=  soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 's-item__info clearfix'})
    for pro in tags:
        title=pro.find('h3',class_='s-item__title').text
        Title.append(title)
        
        price =pro.find('div',class_='s-item__detail s-item__detail--primary').text
        p.append(price)
    
        #print(title,price)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(
    
    {"Title": Title, "Price": p}
)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Title                            Price
0                                                       7S0ponso rPA Eed-1 UJ 0F -1-1  
1    Converse CHUCK TAYLOR All Star Low Top Unisex ...                 $38.95 to $64.95
2    Air Jordan 1 Mid University Gold White Black Y...                          $130.00
3    Air Jordan 1 Mid Metallic Red Gym Red Black Wh...                          $149.95
4    Nike Air Force 1 Low Triple White ‘07 BRAND NE...                           $99.99
..                                                 ...                              ...
465    Salomon S-lab XT 6  Soft Ground Size  Men 11 US                           $50.00
466  Nike Dunk Low Light Bone Tropical Twist (GS) -...                          $170.99
467  Nike Air Force 1 '07 Shoes Black Men's Multi S...                          $100.00
468  12 Mens 13.5 W Reebok Classic Harman Run S Pri...                           $47.99  
469  NIKE SHOX ZOOM AIR Mid High Basketball  Shoes ...                           $50.00  

[470 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: but when import data in csv file they will not give full data in csv file

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move the `for pro in tags` loop into the `for page in range(0, 10)` loop.

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting? So we can help.

Comment: When I move the for pro in tags loop into the for page in range(0, 10) loop they show me

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\ibba.py", line 8, in <module>
    for pro in tags:
NameError: name 'tags' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Few problems: 1) you need the for loop within your loop of pages. and 2) your url syntax is incorrect.

Give this a try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
for page in range(0, 10):
    r =requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=sneakers&_sacat=0&_pgn={page}'.format(page=page)) 
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    tags=  soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': 's-item'})
    for pro in tags:
        try:
            title=pro.find('h3',class_='s-item__title').text.encode("utf-8")
            price=pro.find('div',class_='s-item__detail s-item__detail--primary').text.encode("utf-8")
        except:
            pass
        
    
        print(title,price)
```

Comment: brother it works I am vey thankful but there another issue now  when I am import csv file of my data they show empty csv file

Comment: bro it works it my mistake but it not give full data in csv file

Comment: Ok. Then accept this answer and write a new post. Thats a whole other issue and I can't help you without seeing what your code is to write the csv

Comment: class value  's-item' select only 1  item from each page, you can test it.

Comment: I did test it. It works. It doesn't select only 1 item from each page. What are you talking about?

Comment: @ArslanAziz, to fix your csv, get rid of the encoding in your code. so do `title=pro.find('h3',class_='s-item__title').text` instead of `title=pro.find('h3',class_='s-item__title').text.encode("utf-8")`. Do it for both title and price variables

Answer (score 0):

To extract results from all pages and not just one or ten pages (i.e hardcoded), the best solution is to use an infinite `while` loop and check for something (button, element) that will trigger to exit it.

This solution is better than a hardcoded `for` loop since the `while` loop will run until a certain condition is fulfilled. In our case, this is the presence of a button on the page (`.pagination__next` selector).

Checking if the button exists and moving to the next page:

```py
if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
        params['_pgn'] += 1
    else:
        break
```

Check code with pagination in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-ebay-all-pages-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36",
    }
    
params = {
    '_nkw': 'sneakerss',     # search query  
    '_pgn': 1                # page number
    }

data = []

while True:
    page = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html', params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    
    print(f"Extracting page: {params['_pgn']}")

    print("-" * 10)
    
    for products in soup.select(".s-item__info"):
        title = products.select_one(".s-item__title span").text
        price = products.select_one(".s-item__price").text
        link = products.select_one(".s-item__link")["href"]
        
        data.append({
          "title" : title,
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })

    if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
        params['_pgn'] += 1
    else:
        break

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
Extracting page: 1
----------
[
  {
    "title": "Men's shoes DATE 9 (EU 42) sneakers white leather black suede BG148-42",
    "price": "$166.90",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/275031117789?hash=item400921cfdd:g:kMsAAOSwXzRhlM3v&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAwNBs47deR8e8PTTlQkvbHokYv%2BebkVKKF1o1v6tMxJ4Yl7GODAYbaWBlBGoY6%2BAXAy1Ay0PP1919S%2FPb9rV4%2FWmGwoiqfd5tR4TcahgUlULiaAR8b1QWZz%2BJle3LwwPh7ZCyrAEeQZu6Z1L6%2FHufDGJTiEV6MEa1aYIT7ErUEY8wdGo2L0D7qHhKtdFqx1piOcA5LtYHLxPBRDqFXmjXvVeq2S2c2Xxvu1JJrB6r%2BEQtuwM3m%2FxgoljOQy48lA26iA%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABlBMUPK98f6KYQ"
  },
  {
    "title": "Fashion Running Shoes Men's Walking Athletic Sneakers Tennis Sports Lightweight",
    "price": "$21.99 to $25.99",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/374241964856?hash=item57228f3338:g:lVQAAOSwEDdjFgDl&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4FeR8IbHqB04y4afcJaRYMr%2BNXDhrPrQn%2FtBex%2F76%2Be21v2Q22s89LTKxXzzDChI6PM7kF3HiAjPbP1SVazcZTYhDOA69eyoTeyoKlhQ0g8UF8%2B%2F4Ouvc4kmZ2LIodFQnpmxTXmN6DMby3o60gZOMBGoxyo5AvvjGS9NHmMO0TYn6vHH3RX4ExwuLawJc3Yjx%2BTbyC%2B%2BhMR8ly72gvd2fLu%2F8nVbs8WNqIQj%2BBE0lM07DHLg17o6Ugcy6STNoPWaoU54BaMOYhixu0JkuujfE6h8lgy5%2FLMi1USi4sDPyeP7%7Ctkp%3ABFBM8r3x_oph"
  },
  {
    "title": "adidas Ultraboost 22 Shoes Men's",
    "price": "$133.00 to $190.00",
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/155163747912?hash=item24207ae648:g:WB0AAOSw2qJjRdhe&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4Df80B3%2F9%2Bmu1RODyiDdIg14%2B4fbOWSpAXrxoWnz1Uy6mBcGbSuKwlMzISqXwT39a97yuUVxw3Mnl3IgZ6XmZJVAjPPyb40BYs%2F7lBJdBQjRQpwraxSPIK5LY7%2BMLA3krQ29xgfeA8bYFKL4uqmpkgmhNqjhJoCSlB%2B0yQ8w70STypE9D4t%2FYVMznZ%2BpXFILLYwxu%2Bqw46oudcEwT18dtIm0UvueKugPcIjNl%2B7xlPr7ArjO6uMyAnBiG7HLHGukqaJLlP96%2B01brePidilLfNJ0STEvSjECV7txDIG3TXK%2F%7Ctkp%3ABFBM8r3x_oph"
  },
  # ...
]
```

---

As an alternative, you can use [Ebay Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/ebay-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan that handles blocks and parsing on their backend.

Example code with pagination:

```py
from serpapi import EbaySearch
import os, json

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),  # serpapi api key    
    "engine": "ebay",                 # search engine
    "ebay_domain": "ebay.com",        # ebay domain
    "_nkw": "sneakerss",              # search query
    "_pgn": 1                         # page number 
  # "LH_Sold": "1"                    # shows sold items
}

search = EbaySearch(params)        # where data extraction happens

page_num = 0

data = []

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()     # JSON -> Python dict

    if "error" in results:
        print(results["error"])
        break
    
    for organic_result in results.get("organic_results", []):
        link = organic_result.get("link")
        price = organic_result.get("price")

        data.append({
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })
                    
    page_num += 1
    print(page_num)
    
    if "next" in results.get("pagination", {}):
        params['_pgn'] += 1

    else:
        break

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
    "price": {
      "raw": "$50.00",
      "extracted": 50.0
    },
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/155159964475?hash=item2420412b3b:g:sc4AAOSwBj1jOcJe&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoGu%2FVS9Jqy79HSnvhDrxGfI2MAvPyAO%2BhHiSviy2A%2Bgn%2BYCi8IkFzN2dHBPlVlUgTFe6qGbssF1%2B83svDr2H4K5SnbR79MOdCho1ttV3VXkcgq%2FH0xNnOrr%2Bx5dkpF0jqzJU38Io93wdRt%2B4LZkkQhkXLg0HA%2F%2B%2BRCT9D%2Boyorl0lQBMjpXdDoWsbkcV9eroKOnmMwvQILNGme61V6zFb2Q%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR7iu-f-KYQ"
  },
  {
    "price": {
      "raw": "$168.67",
      "extracted": 168.67
    },
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/125289511527?var=426318775584&epid=5053638274&hash=item1d2bd63a67:g:yUIAAOSwE0libYFy&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4F5dnQv6eqwesf4aXjp2fToBBYgqeE8vREnDFNgHPi%2FKvVwgofgKdEoBtIKP1pM5SoyMa63An1rIMvAsn0iA7MOt%2Bcp8StGY%2BKXfWHbM0T1x287nGBdZZbF7YEIHEpvkM70ZfU32l8VYS%2F6mtT2gkci4tdB8kIzALUS29mjiL3PBhuFZWPmJu1SZqvwgVoBSmiaG0q8AfWNB2OZ5XtT%2Fyt56HjCw9WOKRKxMDT%2BhqEm%2FHt72e8ebO2IwR56BEoLUPPBZ9wT8YR1qpTq6J3qkWMPZiQNYOnlsu0BDGT58Q13t%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR7iu-f-KYQ"
  },
  # ...
]
```